# Difference between these two lines?

Tags: javascript

What is the advantage of using `obj.loc++` instead of `this.loc++` in the 
fourth line?

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
    obj.loc = loc;
    obj.move = function() {
        this.loc++;
    };
    return obj;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
amy.move();
```

It was a little explained on this video, but the difference between these two still isn't clear to me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oi0NY8Pen8

In this video it's been said that when we use `this.loc++`, it gets bound to a new value, every time `move` is invoked. But when we use `obj.loc++` then each time we call car `carlike` function, a new closure scope is created and therefore the `obj` variable will always refer to exactly one car object. What does it mean?

Comment: FYA - Is anything answering your question or if you have got your own answer then please post it, so that other can be benefited from it ..

Answer (score 2):

If you use `this`, you set its value when you call it:

```js
amy.move();         // Called with this === amy
amy.move.call(foo); // Called with this === foo
```

If you use `obj`, it will always be `obj`, independently of how `move` is called.

Answer (score 0):

That is a video from the Udacity Object Oriented JavaScript course. Some lessons before the instructor teaches us about `this` keyword.

`this` refers to the object/caller of the function/method. Usually it is the `object` that is left of the `dot`. (In the answer of @Oriol `this` is overwritten in the special `call` function as a parameter.)

And that is really the difference, @Oriol is right.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have understood it correct that there is no difference in result whether you use `this.loc` or `obj.loc`.

Short answer to your question is there is no real direct advantage or dis-advantage of using `obj.loc++` instead of `this.loc++`.

**Explanation:** There are 2 important context in which you should understand `this`.

1. Global context:  In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not. Since it is not your case, so let's not dig.
2. Function context:  Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called. In **non-strict mode**, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object. In **strict mode**, the value of this remains at whatever it's set to when entering the execution context. If it's not defined, it remains undefined. It can also be set to any value, such as null or 42 or "I am not this".

Read [this from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more detailed explanation.

Now, in your case whether you run in strict mode or non-strict mode, whether you will use `this` or `obj` you will see same results, because when you use `this` then again it becomes your function context and you access `loc` on `this`.

Now, talking about convention, suppose there is another global variable named `loc` and when you use `this.loc++;` inside your `carlike` function then still `this` will run in function context and will increment `loc` of `carlike` function but there is poor readability, at-least for novice, that whether it will increment global `loc` or local `loc`.

So, **to sum up** using `obj.loc++;` is a better idea.